# How to provide config file for Ruby command line utility written in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, command-line, configuration-files

I have a command line utility written in Ruby using `GLI` framework. I would like to have configuration for my command line utility in my home directory, using Ruby itself as DSL to handle it (similar to `Gemfile` or `Rakefile`).

I have in class ConfigData in folder lib/myapp. The class looks like following way:

```
class ConfigData
  @@data = {}

  class ConfigItem
    def initialize
      @data = {}
    end
    def missing_method(name, *args)
      @data[name] = args[0]
    end
  end

  def self.add(section)
    item = ConfigItem.new()
    yield item
    @@data[section]=item
  end

end
```

Now, what I would like to have, is the config file, preferrably with name `Myappfile`, in current working folder, with the following content

```
add('section1') do |i|
  i.param1 'Some data'
  i.param2 'More data'
end
```

When this code was included between `class` and `end` of ConfigData, it worked fine. But now I would like to have it placed in the working folder, where I start the application.

I tried require('./Myappfile') between `class` and `end` of ConfigData, but it doesn't work for me. I tried to read the source codes of rake, but it is not very much clear to me.

Any hint how this can be solved?

Comment: @millimoose: Please don't use normal eval. Please.

Comment: I know I should not use `eval` and thus I'm looking for another, better and perhaps cannonical way of doing this...

Comment: @TomBurger: Just not normal eval. Check out my answer, mainly the security part.

Comment: @TomBurger: `instance_eval` is the canonical way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate code within the context of an instance, which is what you want to do, you need the `instance_eval()` method. Never, ever, use normal eval. Ever. Anyway, here's how you'd load your fingi file and get the data:

```
config = ConfigData.new
config.instance_eval(File.read("Myconfig"))
#Access configuration data here from the config object
```

That simple. After you've loaded the object in that way, you can access values of the object.

WARNING: This is not very secure. This is actually a gaping security hole. Here's the secure version:

```
f = Fiber.new {str = File.read("Myconfig"); $SAFE = 4; config = ConfigData.new; config.instance_eval(str); Fiber.yield config}
confdata = f.resume
#Access configuration data here from confdata.
```

This executes the external code in a (sort of) sandbox, so that it can't do anything dastardly.

---

Also, why don't you just use a YAML config? Unless configuration needs to run code like `pwd` or access RUBY_VERSION, YAML is much simpler and more secure, in addition to being more failproof.

Comment: Basically it works, but $SAFE = 4 is causing File.read to fail as unsafe operation - Any idea how to do it better?

Comment: Ad YAML - I expect to do some smarter things in config, not only key-value mapping, thus I would like to have some flexibility there...

Comment: @TomBurger: Fixed first issue.

Comment: thanks, it works, but still partly only. However for this follow-up problem I've created follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012732/ruby-collecting-configuration-in-hash-is-insecure-any-alternative

Comment: @TomBurger You have to think about what exactly you’re protecting against that you need to use `SAFE`. Given that this is a command line app, the user already has a prompt and can run any code they want. Using `SAFE` is mainly to protect against malicious input from outsiders, but in this case the input is provided by the user themselves (it’s a file in their directory). For example Bundler doesn’t make use of `SAFE` when [evaluating the Gemfile](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/v1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb#L32).

Comment: @matt: Either way, better safe then sorry. it's not that hard to get a malicious file onto the drive, the hard part is getting it executed. This helps prevent it.